# How to include a android native extension (.so) into an AIR native extension (.ane)?

Tags: android, jar, air, java-native-interface, air-native-extension

I'm currently trying to find a solution to have an AIR native extension including a C - library for Android that is using JNI.

So far, I tried to pack the .so lib into a jar, which then is packaged into the ane.
As I learned [here](http://frommyplayground.com/how-to-load-native-jni-library-from-jar), I have to unpack the .so from the .jar first in order to access it.

The code found there seems to be working for a regular android project, unfortunatly when doing this for a .jar which is then packaged into an .ane, it seems to lose scope, resulting in a

```
FileNotFoundException: File path/to/my/lib was not found inside JAR
```

I already double and triple checked all paths and the contents of my jar. It's all there and spelled correctly.

Q1: How do I get access to the .so from actionscript?

Q2: Is there any other way to package/address the .so besides the regular extension-jar into the ane?

Q3: I really don't know much about the inner working of the .ane mechanism. Is it also possible to skip the .jar-wrapping and use the .so directly from actionscript?

As always, many thanks for any input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It becomes a bad habit of me to answer my own questions, but anyway...

Sometimes the docs can help. [Here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSf268776665d7970d-2482335412ffea65006-8000.html) in the adobe docs I finally found the solution.

Simply copying the .so to the libs/armeabi-v7a folder in my ane package directory includes the lib into the ane, so I can use the .so from inside the java code of my extension.

Sorry for bothering.